# Difference in image display (MATLAB and VISUAL STUDIO)

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-2012, image-processing

```
for(i=0;i<m_bitmap.bmHeight-1; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<m_bitmap.bmWidth-1; j++)
    {                   
        r = GetRValue(imagearr1[i][j]);
        g = GetGValue(imagearr1[i][j]);
        b = GetBValue(imagearr1[i][j]);

        temp_r = r/255.00;
        temp_g = g/255.00;
        temp_b = b/255.00;

        /////////////////XYZ conversion////////////////

        temp_X = (0.412453*temp_r + 0.357580*temp_g + 0.180423*temp_b);
        temp_Y = (0.212671*temp_r + 0.715160*temp_g + 0.072169*temp_b);
        temp_Z = (0.019334*temp_r + 0.119193*temp_g + 0.950227*temp_b);

        ///////////////Normalisation/////////////

        X = temp_X/0.950456;
        Y = temp_Y/1.00;
        Z = temp_Z/1.088754;


        if ( X > 0.008856 ) 
        {
            X = pow(X , (1.00/3.00) );
        }
        else
        {
            X = ( 7.787 * X ) + ( 16.00 / 116.00 );
        }
        if ( Y > 0.008856 ) 
        {
            Y = pow (Y , (1.00/3.00) );
        }
        else
        {
            Y = ( 7.787 * Y ) + ( 16.00 / 116.00 );
        }
        if ( Z > 0.008856 )
        {
            Z = pow (Z , (1.00/3.00) );
        }
        else     
        {
            Z = ( 7.787 * Z ) + ( 16.00 / 116.00 );
        }

        C_L = ( 116.00 * Y ) - 16.00;
        C_a = (500.00 * ( X - Y )+128);
        C_b = 200.00 * ( Y - Z );


        imagearr2[i][j] = RGB(C_a,C_a,C_a);
    }
}

k=0;

for(i=m_bitmap.bmHeight-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    for(j=0; j<m_bitmap.bmWidth; j++)
    {
            *(byte+k) = GetBValue(imagearr2[i][j]);         
            k++;
            *(byte+k) = GetGValue(imagearr2[i][j]);         
            k++;
            *(byte+k) = GetRValue(imagearr2[i][j]);                                 
            k++;
    }           

    k=k+padding;
}


SetDIBitsToDevice(
   m_hmainmemdc, 0, 0, m_bitmap.bmWidth, m_bitmap.bmHeight, 0, 0 , 0,
   m_bitmap.bmHeight, byte, &bm,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
BitBlt(dc.m_hDC,0,0,rect.right,rect.bottom, m_hmainmemdc,0,0, SRCCOPY);
```

Hi,

I am converting an image (colour) from RGB to LAB colour space and displaying it.

I tried it in MATLAB as well as VISUAL STUDIO but both of them giving me different images (difference it contrast) (I am only interested in *a* part of L*a*b image).

Please see the code which I used to convert then in MATLAB and Visual Studio.
I Checked for precision errors in this and understood both compilers are giving me same numericals.

Same formula and logic I used in MATLAB but I did not add 128 in the final *a* value, and for displaying it I used this command

**"imshow(C_a, [])"**

I would like to have result image as in MATLAB, for that what type of conversion I should Use?

Thanks in advance!

**Visual Studio**
[image: Result Image for Visual Studio]

**MATLAB**
[image: Result Image in MATLAB]

Comment: For your matlab image, what is `max(C_a(;))` and what is `class(C_a)`?

Comment: I hope this what you asked (The function you wrote give me an error in matlab)  max(max(C_a)) = 77.28 , min(min(a)) =  -24.6582, class(C_a) = double.                           And I also read imshow(C_a, [ ] ) is increesing the dynamic range of the image this may be the reason behind it in that case all I need how MATLAB doing this? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the actual pixel intensity values are the same.

My rough guess is that the reason you observe this difference in contrast is the fact that you stretch the visualized intensity range with `imshow(C_a, [])`.

Try plain `imshow(C_a)` and check what you get.

Comment: I've alrady tried imshow(C_a). It will give me a black and white image. But it still different from  image given by the visual studio.(Actually adding 128 in C_a is to convert image to 8 bit format I used this conversion formula to convert the image [link] http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html)

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed it is because of stretching the intensity range by the display function imshow(C_a, [])

please see

http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2016/03/21/matlab-image-display-autoscaling-values-with-imshow/

and also present in MATLAB documentation

and why I am getting image in visual studio/opencv like that is; Lab conversion function will add 128 to every pixel in-order to convert the image range as 0-255 (as Lab colour space will have negative values)